# Slidetoggle close div when another is clicked

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Okay, so I am sure that the obvious is just escaping me, but I have a site I am working on that I am trying to get the "extra" menu to work as div's that slide into view.  The problem I am having is getting the previous div to slide back down when the next item is clicked.  Right now when each item is clicked the div slides into view and just overlaps the other one.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  Here is the link to see what it is doing: http://interbay.liveimagination.com/about.htm

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="philosophyPopup">
<div id="philosophyDashboard">
<div id="philosophyInfo"><h1>Philosophy</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis sem at mauris vulputate sit amet vehicula diam ultrices. Nulla in magna eget mauris commodo tincidunt vel in leo. Sed non turpis libero. Duis posuere, nisi in semper sagittis, enim velit vestibulum leo, id consequat ligula odio id nunc. Nunc tempus tellus quis nulla molestie tempor. Pellentesque convallis dui a lectus vestibulum ultricies. Suspendisse congue, arcu vitae iaculis blandit, felis tortor eleifend lacus, vel facilisis nunc ipsum ut ipsum. Curabitur sed lorem at massa commodo ultricies eget vel sapien. Quisque sit amet odio massa, sed adipiscing velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas adipiscing turpis et urna cursus non sodales est tristique. Integer interdum, elit vel fermentum iaculis, justo est venenatis augue, sit amet pharetra magna diam id odio.
</p>
<p>Sed venenatis sagittis nibh, gravida eleifend est ullamcorper at. Ut et leo id leo placerat vehicula ac in tellus. Suspendisse volutpat luctus metus, consequat luctus mi dignissim at. Quisque non enim velit, imperdiet gravida nisi. Nam eget elit quis urna adipiscing porttitor eu non nunc. Ut in urna nec augue vestibulum auctor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus cursus tortor vel augue rutrum molestie.
</p>
<p>Morbi faucibus dui sit amet massa commodo dictum. Praesent facilisis euismod ligula nec interdum. Sed tristique, tortor id blandit eleifend, eros nibh viverra ligula, a convallis velit metus vel turpis. Suspendisse lobortis lobortis sem, sed molestie neque aliquam eu. Curabitur et consequat dolor. Nullam magna orci, rutrum at luctus eget, sagittis non sapien. Etiam id fermentum lectus. Aliquam ut lacinia purus. Vestibulum lorem arcu, condimentum ac ullamcorper sed, vestibulum in sem. Vivamus tristique tortor ut sem congue dignissim suscipit nunc egestas.
</p>
<p>Mauris quam tellus, auctor at dictum at, laoreet a est. Phasellus ut metus nec dolor porta convallis. Nunc laoreet massa at purus aliquet ultrices. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ornare, enim vitae molestie tincidunt, est elit hendrerit sem, vel commodo eros ipsum non tellus. Nam nunc ante, dignissim eu pellentesque eget, ornare eget sapien. Pellentesque nec ipsum erat. Pellentesque consequat ipsum sed sem facilisis quis cursus nulla tempus. Suspendisse non ligula convallis lacus venenatis blandit. Cras eleifend consectetur tortor, eu cursus elit iaculis a. Nulla facilisi.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="aboutusPopup">
<div id="aboutusDashboard">
<div id="aboutusInfo"><h1>About US</h1>
<p>Interbay Veterinary Care Center has been providing excellent medical care to pets in Magnolia and Queen Anne since 1974.  Our hospital is designed to provide clients and patients a veterinary experience unlike any they have had elsewhere.  In a profession without a widely accepted standard of care, practicing good, and modern medicine, is a choice for veterinarians. 
</p>
<p>
We have made that choice and strive to practice thorough, in-depth, current, and modern medicine.  We strongly encourage preventative medicine and take the time to fully inform our clients as to the nature of their pet's overall health.  Our doctors and staff engage in regular continuing education to keep informed of current developments in medicine, and we are confident that our patient care and client service is unsurpassed.
</p>
<p>Interbay Veterinary Care Center has been providing excellent medical care to pets in Magnolia and Queen Anne since 1974.  Our hospital is designed to provide clients and patients a veterinary experience unlike any they have had elsewhere.  In a profession without a widely accepted standard of care, practicing good, and modern medicine, is a choice for veterinarians. 
</p>
<p>
We have made that choice and strive to practice thorough, in-depth, current, and modern medicine.  We strongly encourage preventative medicine and take the time to fully inform our clients as to the nature of their pet's overall health.  Our doctors and staff engage in regular continuing education to keep informed of current developments in medicine, and we are confident that our patient care and client service is unsurpassed.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="tourPopup">
<div id="tourDashboard">
<div id="tourInfo"><h1>Tour</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis sem at mauris vulputate sit amet vehicula diam ultrices. Nulla in magna eget mauris commodo tincidunt vel in leo. Sed non turpis libero. Duis posuere, nisi in semper sagittis, enim velit vestibulum leo, id consequat ligula odio id nunc. Nunc tempus tellus quis nulla molestie tempor. Pellentesque convallis dui a lectus vestibulum ultricies. Suspendisse congue, arcu vitae iaculis blandit, felis tortor eleifend lacus, vel facilisis nunc ipsum ut ipsum. Curabitur sed lorem at massa commodo ultricies eget vel sapien. Quisque sit amet odio massa, sed adipiscing velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas adipiscing turpis et urna cursus non sodales est tristique. Integer interdum, elit vel fermentum iaculis, justo est venenatis augue, sit amet pharetra magna diam id odio.
</p>
<p>Sed venenatis sagittis nibh, gravida eleifend est ullamcorper at. Ut et leo id leo placerat vehicula ac in tellus. Suspendisse volutpat luctus metus, consequat luctus mi dignissim at. Quisque non enim velit, imperdiet gravida nisi. Nam eget elit quis urna adipiscing porttitor eu non nunc. Ut in urna nec augue vestibulum auctor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus cursus tortor vel augue rutrum molestie.
</p>
<p>Morbi faucibus dui sit amet massa commodo dictum. Praesent facilisis euismod ligula nec interdum. Sed tristique, tortor id blandit eleifend, eros nibh viverra ligula, a convallis velit metus vel turpis. Suspendisse lobortis lobortis sem, sed molestie neque aliquam eu. Curabitur et consequat dolor. Nullam magna orci, rutrum at luctus eget, sagittis non sapien. Etiam id fermentum lectus. Aliquam ut lacinia purus. Vestibulum lorem arcu, condimentum ac ullamcorper sed, vestibulum in sem. Vivamus tristique tortor ut sem congue dignissim suscipit nunc egestas.
</p>
<p>Mauris quam tellus, auctor at dictum at, laoreet a est. Phasellus ut metus nec dolor porta convallis. Nunc laoreet massa at purus aliquet ultrices. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ornare, enim vitae molestie tincidunt, est elit hendrerit sem, vel commodo eros ipsum non tellus. Nam nunc ante, dignissim eu pellentesque eget, ornare eget sapien. Pellentesque nec ipsum erat. Pellentesque consequat ipsum sed sem facilisis quis cursus nulla tempus. Suspendisse non ligula convallis lacus venenatis blandit. Cras eleifend consectetur tortor, eu cursus elit iaculis a. Nulla facilisi.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="joinusPopup">
<div id="joinusDashboard">
<div id="joinusInfo"><h1>Join Us</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis sem at mauris vulputate sit amet vehicula diam ultrices. Nulla in magna eget mauris commodo tincidunt vel in leo. Sed non turpis libero. Duis posuere, nisi in semper sagittis, enim velit vestibulum leo, id consequat ligula odio id nunc. Nunc tempus tellus quis nulla molestie tempor. Pellentesque convallis dui a lectus vestibulum ultricies. Suspendisse congue, arcu vitae iaculis blandit, felis tortor eleifend lacus, vel facilisis nunc ipsum ut ipsum. Curabitur sed lorem at massa commodo ultricies eget vel sapien. Quisque sit amet odio massa, sed adipiscing velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas adipiscing turpis et urna cursus non sodales est tristique. Integer interdum, elit vel fermentum iaculis, justo est venenatis augue, sit amet pharetra magna diam id odio.
</p>
<p>Sed venenatis sagittis nibh, gravida eleifend est ullamcorper at. Ut et leo id leo placerat vehicula ac in tellus. Suspendisse volutpat luctus metus, consequat luctus mi dignissim at. Quisque non enim velit, imperdiet gravida nisi. Nam eget elit quis urna adipiscing porttitor eu non nunc. Ut in urna nec augue vestibulum auctor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus cursus tortor vel augue rutrum molestie.
</p>
<p>Morbi faucibus dui sit amet massa commodo dictum. Praesent facilisis euismod ligula nec interdum. Sed tristique, tortor id blandit eleifend, eros nibh viverra ligula, a convallis velit metus vel turpis. Suspendisse lobortis lobortis sem, sed molestie neque aliquam eu. Curabitur et consequat dolor. Nullam magna orci, rutrum at luctus eget, sagittis non sapien. Etiam id fermentum lectus. Aliquam ut lacinia purus. Vestibulum lorem arcu, condimentum ac ullamcorper sed, vestibulum in sem. Vivamus tristique tortor ut sem congue dignissim suscipit nunc egestas.
</p>
<p>Mauris quam tellus, auctor at dictum at, laoreet a est. Phasellus ut metus nec dolor porta convallis. Nunc laoreet massa at purus aliquet ultrices. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ornare, enim vitae molestie tincidunt, est elit hendrerit sem, vel commodo eros ipsum non tellus. Nam nunc ante, dignissim eu pellentesque eget, ornare eget sapien. Pellentesque nec ipsum erat. Pellentesque consequat ipsum sed sem facilisis quis cursus nulla tempus. Suspendisse non ligula convallis lacus venenatis blandit. Cras eleifend consectetur tortor, eu cursus elit iaculis a. Nulla facilisi.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#philosophyOpen').click(function () {
    $('#philosophyPopup #philosophyDashboard').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 300);
    $(this).toggleClass('philosophyClose');
  });  

$('#aboutusOpen').click(function () {
    $('#aboutusPopup #aboutusDashboard').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 300);
    $(this).toggleClass('aboutusClose');
  });

$('#tourOpen').click(function () {
    $('#tourPopup #tourDashboard').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 300);
    $(this).toggleClass('tourClose');
  });

$('#joinusOpen').click(function () {
    $('#joinusPopup #joinusDashboard').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 300);
    $(this).toggleClass('joinusClose');
  });
}); 

</script>
```

Here are the id elements:

```
<a id="philosophyOpen" class="philosophybtn"></a> <a id="aboutusOpen" class="teambtn"></a> <a id="tourOpen" class="tourbtn"></a> <a id="joinusOpen" class="joinusbtn"></a>
```

Comment: What are the #id<Open> elements with the click event handler defined? I can't see them on your html code

Comment: Added a possibile solution as answer; give a try to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the accordion effect; with your actual code I ended up with this.

I use a globally scoped variable `currElem` to handle the last used acordion element; than when the accordion element is clicked I check if is the same element using the jQuery [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

> Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a
>   selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of
>   these elements matches the given arguments.

The final code looks like:

```
var currElem;

$(function () {
    $('#philosophyOpen').click(function () {

        if (currElem && !currElem.is('#philosophyPopup #philosophyDashboard')) $(currElem).hide();

        $('#philosophyPopup #philosophyDashboard').slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
        $(this).toggleClass('philosophyClose');

        currElem = $('#philosophyPopup #philosophyDashboard');
    });

    $('#aboutusOpen').click(function () {

        if (currElem && !currElem.is('#aboutusPopup #aboutusDashboard')) $(currElem).hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('aboutusClose');

        $('#aboutusPopup #aboutusDashboard').slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);

        currElem = $('#aboutusPopup #aboutusDashboard');
    });

    $('#tourOpen').click(function () {

        if (currElem && !currElem.is('#tourPopup #tourDashboard')) $(currElem).hide();

        $('#tourPopup #tourDashboard').slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
        $(this).toggleClass('tourClose');

        currElem = $('#aboutusPopup #aboutusDashboard');
    });

    $('#joinusOpen').click(function () {

        if (currElem && !currElem.is('#joinusPopup #joinusDashboard')) $(currElem).hide();

        $('#joinusPopup #joinusDashboard').slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 300).addClass('accordClose');
        $(this).toggleClass('joinusClose');

        currElem = $('#joinusPopup #joinusDashboard');
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Ypr7F/

Comment: @LisaFrench glad to help you! If the answer solve the question accept it using the green mark